# SQL. Query for vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table that has more than one date fields (say six or seven) and I just want to retrieve only the dates that match today's date. Please help. Really appreciate it thanks

Comment: Please share some code or use GETDATE() function to map your field with the current date

Comment: Would you mind being more specific about it. Sorry I am just a rookie pitcher. Thanks

Comment: Please post your SQL table structure here. Then I can give you the exact answer.

Comment: @HarshaW `GetDate()` in Access?      can you not go with `where yourdatefield = DATE() OR yourotherdatefield = DATE()`.....   or if you want all the fields to = todays date use `AND` instead of `OR` (`DATE()` gives you todays date)

Comment: Hey Fred - I did similar to what you suggest here but no record we're in the result

Comment: Hi Harsha- my table looks what you see here:  table1 and fields are protectid, project title, dates1, date2, date3, date4, date5 and date6. Dates here refer to different stage in project

Comment: Seems the answer given by @JCalcines isn't exactly what you're after.  Could you add a picture of your table (or portion of, or mockup of) to your question (using Edit) - `Print Screen` and `MS Paint` and upload to here using the `image` icon at the top of the edit question bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific problem, so the best way to get the result you want is to code some part as an script on access.

For getting those rows where at least one date is the same as today's date, you should use something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table t
WHERE Date() IN (t.field1, t.field2, ...)
```

You should add all the fields you want to check inside `IN` clause.

On the Access for you should be able to process the data.

Comment: Great!! Harsha I'll check and let you know in case of any questions. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi there, I tried the following code (SELECT * FROM Table t WHERE Date() IN (t.field1, t.field2, ...) but it pulls all the dates which is not exactly expected. Your thoughts please

Comment: actually what i need is that the result from the query should serve as a report and that report should show the project id and project title (the first two columns) along with only the dates that equal today's date. not all date fields are required in this result. the bottom line is that this result should act as Todo list for today. i guess i am clear about what i intend to get. Thanks

Comment: You should update your question with this new information